# Fedora init boot sequence

Tags: linux, fedora, init

I am interested in Linux Fedora's boot sequence, specifically starting at the user-space init sequence.   What are the good sources of information on this front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora [recently switched](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/systemd) to [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd).

With systemd there's no "sequence" in the traditional sense. Just [read up on systemd on 0pointer.de](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-docs.html) (don't worry it's english)